# Create Master Timer Job and inherit from it in multiple Instances

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, timer-jobs

Is it possible to create a "Master" timer job in SharePoint 2013 and lets say inherit from it in future timer jobs?

I want to create a lets call it template and build further timer jobs on top of this base. Like you can inherit from a Class or something.

If it is not possible this way, is there a alternative way to archieve what I wrote above?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a template, you can create a Interface class. Example:

```
public interface ICustomMethods
{
    void CustomMember1();
    int CustomMember2();
}
```

and then inherit it in your public classes that are created for your timer jobs.

```
public class CustomJob: SPJobDefinition, ICustomMethods
{
void CustomMember1()
{
//Your Code
}
int CustomMember2()
{
//Your Code
return int;
}


   ..

}
```

However, If you want to avoid code duplicacy, you can create a base class, inherit it and use its members.